# How to extract normalized data from the ember-data store?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am working on caching my ember-data store to local storage. On first load I query the server load the data into the store and then load it into local storage. On subsequent page loads I pull the data from localstorage and load it into the store. I am able to do this using the [pushMany](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_pushMany) method.

The store's `pushMany` method requires normalized data. Payload from the server is normalized by passing it through the models serializer. Once the normalized data is in the store it seems reasonable to believe that it should be possible to pull normalized data out.

**So how do you pull normalized data out of the store?**

There is a `_data` property on each model. The '_data' property only works with flat models. More complex models `_data` property contains instantiated relationships.

I would like to avoid having to serialize/deserialize more than once.

[This](https://gist.github.com/arenoir/528c4d77c9398e519984#file-local-cache-js-L49) is my current implementation. The problem with the `toJson` method is it has to load all the associations including async relations that have not been resolved.  I think there is a fundamental issue regarding how ember data resolves relationship primary/foreign keys.

Comment: I dont know if this is what you mean but you can get records from the store without making a request server by using all - via http://emberjs.com/guides/models/finding-records/#toc_finding-all-records-of-a-type    
"To get a list of records already loaded into the store, without making another network request, use all instead."

`var posts = this.store.all('post');` // => no network request

Comment: here is a gist https://gist.github.com/arenoir/528c4d77c9398e519984#file-local-cache-js-L47

Comment: this works for models without relationships. IMO there should be a method on the model for extracting the raw normalized data.

Comment: yeah i was thinking that the solution couldnt be that simple....

Answer (score 2):

A good starting point for your problem could be the implementation of [toJSON](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/serializers/json_serializer.js#L460) from ember-data.

As you mentioned, the problem with toJSON is that it is resolving all the associations. For belongsTo relationships it's easy to avoid this issue by using _data to get the *id* of the related object.

```js
customToJSON: function(record) {
  var json = {};
  json.id = record.get('id');

  var serializer = DS.JSONSerializer.create({ container: record.container });

  record.eachAttribute(function(key, attribute) {
    serializer.serializeAttribute(record, json, key, attribute);
  }, this);

  record.eachRelationship(function(key, relationship) {
    if (relationship.kind === 'belongsTo') {
        json[relationship.key] = record._data[relationship.key].id;
    }
  });

  return json;
}
```

Comment: As of today I don't think there is a good answer to this problem.  The ember data team is working on it.  This snapshot api looks promising. https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/2623. Thanks for the answer I will award the bounty to you.